# Removing HTML url tags in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am writing an iOS app that downloads some data from a server that's not under my control. I am not using custom data detectors. The strings in the returned JSON still contain their HTML url tags, and I want to remove them because I want to display the strings in a UITextView, and these kind of strings

```
<strong><a href="http://instagram.com/emotionslive" rel="nofollow">Instagram</a></strong> / <strong><a href="http://www.behance.net/creativemints" rel="nofollow">Behance</a></strong>

<a href="http://readdle.com/" rel="nofollow"><strong>Live Now</strong></a>
```

What I really want is this:

> [Instagram](http://instagram.com/emotionslive) [Behance](http://www.behance.net/creativemints)
>
> [Live Now](http://www.behance.net/creativemints)

What is the best way to go about this?

1. Should I strip the url tags from the text using regex?
2. Would I lose the link "descriptions" (in the above example, "Instagram" and "Behance") when I do that?
3. Would this be way easier using a UIWebView?

If this would be too hard/impossible, it'd be okay to only have the urls, without their descriptions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I strip the url tags from the text using regex?

No.  HTML is too complex to be properly parsed using a RegEx.  You'll need an XML parser.

> Would I lose the link "descriptions" (in the above example, "Instagram" and "Behance") when I do that?

You wouldn't have to using an XML parser.  Using a RegEx, you might, especially if you can't control exactly what's returned.

> Would this be way easier using a UIWebView?

Yep.  That's what I would do, unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Here's a well-written approach to stripping the HTML, if you need that: https://gist.github.com/leighmcculloch/1202238/raw/9b106fbd49e8d4f79fd49ac6018254b13d0b645e/NSString_stripHtml.m

Comment: That is nice for removing all text between tags, but I want to preserve the url...

Comment: It's just meant to give you a start with NSXMLParser.  You can use the other delegate methods to build an array of URLs using a similar approach.